# Spring Boot: custom AutoConfiguration class fails to find properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a library for a `FooService`.

Here's it's AutoConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FooProperties.class)
public class FooServiceAutoConfigure {

    @Autowired
    FooProperties config;

    @Bean
    public FooService getFooService() throws Exception {
           return new FooService(config.username, config.password)

    }
}
```

Here's the FooProperties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class FooProperties {
    String username;
    String password;
}
```

In `resources/META-INF/spring.factories` I have the following line:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.my.company.FooServiceAutoConfigure
```

In my main project (which is a `@SpringBootApplication`), I have:

- A Maven dependency to this library.
- foo.username and foo.password in application.properties
- Some `@Autowired FooService`.

I can see in the logs that Spring Boot is trying to instantiate FooService but the config.username and config.password are nulls. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I'll answer for future readers:

There weren't setters for `FooProperties`